# How to create all combination of elements of certain length by intentional lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I would like to ask how to create all combinations of elements of a certain length by intentional lists in Haskell? Here is the example:
Function *combo* is taking two arguments list of elements - *xs* and value - *n*, the goal is to create all possible combinations of elements in xs of length n by intentional lists.
For example:
*combo [1,2,3] 2*
should return
*[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]*

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: What did you try, what is not working?

Comment: What is an "intentional list"?

Comment: [(x,y) | x <- xs, y <- xs]

Comment: @dfeuer: I would guess it is something like a generator in other languages.

Comment: aha, so list comprehensions, then.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using a combinatorics library, but can also easily be done yourself.
A small example I made:

```
import Data.List

permutations' _ [] = []
permutations' 0 _  = []
permutations' n xs | n > length xs = error "n can't be larger than length of input"
                   | otherwise = permute n xs []

permute 0 xs ys = [ys]
permute n xs ys = concatMap (\x -> foo (n-1) (x `delete` xs) (ys ++ [x])) xs
```

The 'magic' is happening in premute where a simple combinatorics is applied.
You start off with an empty list of solutions which is extended until the character limit `n` is reached. The input xs e.g. [1,2,3] is mapped, thus each character in xs is fed into the lambda function. In the lambda the x is appended to the already existing result. In the first loop ys is empty thus only x is added. In subsequent calls to permute the xs list is shrunk and ys is appended with the value that xs is shrunk with. Thus growing the result until char limit is reached and subsequently removing characters from xs to prevent duplicate entries.

A walkthrough of `permute 2 [1,2,3] []` might look like this:

```
(\1 -> foo (2-1) [2,3] [] ++ [1])
  - (\2 -> foo (1-1) [3] [1] ++ [2])
    - [1,2], since we hit the first pattern where n = 0
  - (\3 -> foo (1-1) [2] [1] ++ [3])
    - [1,3], since we hit the first pattern where n = 0
(\2 ....
(\3 ....
```